# How to tell which WINEPREFIX is in use

Tags: wine

Is there a command to see which wineprefix is currently active when I run `wine`?

Comment: do you want to find the wineprefix from inside the windows environment or from outside?

Comment: @lesmana, ideally both

Answer (score 5):

From "inside" the windows environment you can read the environment variable `WINEPREFIX`. Here is how you can do that from `cmd`:

```
$ WINEPREFIX=/home/lesmana/tmp/somewineprefix wine cmd
(bunch of wine output)
Z:\home\lesmana> echo %WINEPREFIX%
/home/lesmana/tmp/somewineprefix
```

You can inspect other environment variables using the `cmd` command `set`.

If you started wine without `WINEPREFIX` then there is no `WINEPREFIX` variable set. In that case the wineprefix should be the default (`$HOME/.wine`).

I found no easy or official way to get the wineprefix from "outside" the wine environment. Here is a hack:

First you need the PID of the wineserver process:

```
$ pgrep -fl wineserver
5197 wineserver
```

Then you can peek in the environment variables of the process:

```
$ cat /proc/5197/environ | tr '\0' '\n' | grep -i wine
WINEDLLOVERRIDES=winemenubuilder.exe=d;
WINEPREFIX=/home/lesmana/tmp/somewineprefix
_=/usr/bin/wine
WINELOADERNOEXEC=1
```

Again, if you started wine without `WINEPREFIX` then there will be no `WINEPREFIX` variable.

Alternatively you can check the file descriptors of the process:

```
$ ls -l /proc/5197/fd | grep wine
lr-x------ 1 lesmana users 64 25. Sep 15:27 114 -> /home/lesmana/tmp/somewineprefix/drive_c/windows
lr-x------ 1 lesmana users 64 25. Sep 15:27 32 -> /home/lesmana/tmp/somewineprefix/drive_c/windows
lr-x------ 1 lesmana users 64 25. Sep 15:27 4 -> /home/lesmana/tmp/somewineprefix
lr-x------ 1 lesmana users 64 25. Sep 15:27 48 -> /home/lesmana/tmp/somewineprefix/drive_c/windows/system32
lr-x------ 1 lesmana users 64 25. Sep 15:27 5 -> /tmp/.wine-1000/server-802-2e0ac4 (deleted)
l-wx------ 1 lesmana users 64 25. Sep 15:27 6 -> /tmp/.wine-1000/server-802-2e0ac4/lock (deleted)
```

There is one problem: if there are multiple wineserver processes then you have to find which wineserver belongs to which wine process. Again I found no easy way to make this correlation. The only way I found is by inspecting the timestamps of the processes.

```
$ ps -ef
...
lesmana   5096  5085  0 22:33 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/sh /home/lesmana/bin/wine cmd
lesmana   5097  5096  0 22:33 pts/2    00:00:00 cmd
lesmana   5100   614  0 22:33 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/wineserver
lesmana   5104   614  0 22:33 ?        00:00:00 C:\windows\system32\services.exe
lesmana   5110   614  0 22:33 ?        00:00:00 C:\windows\system32\explorer.exe /desktop
lesmana   5144   614  0 22:33 ?        00:00:03 C:\windows\system32\winedevice.exe
lesmana   5193  5093  0 22:34 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/sh /home/lesmana/bin/wine cmd
lesmana   5194  5193  0 22:34 pts/3    00:00:00 cmd
lesmana   5197   614  0 22:34 ?        00:00:06 /usr/bin/wineserver
lesmana   5201   614  0 22:34 ?        00:00:00 C:\windows\system32\services.exe
lesmana   5207   614  0 22:34 ?        00:00:00 C:\windows\system32\explorer.exe /desktop
lesmana   5345   614  0 22:34 ?        00:00:03 C:\windows\system32\winedevice.exe
...
```

Here are two wine processes and two wineserver processes started one minute apart. It is possible to get `ps` to report the time in seconds if needed.

Unfortunately the wineserver process is started as some sort of daemon and is not a child of the wine process. So no luck with PPID.